# Is it possible in three.js to crop the viewport?

Tags: three.js, rendering, webgl, crop, viewport

I have a scene with a sphere in the middle and a camera spinning around it. Now I was wondering if it is possible with Three.JS to make a crop of this viewport so that the sphere for example would appear on the left or right.

I'm not looking to moving the camera or looking at a point besides the sphere, since that would distort the perspective, but a clip or crop of the rendering.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this example help you? (It fails in Safari on my machine, though.) http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_filters.html

Comment: Ah yes, I did notice the renderer.scissorTest() and renderer.setScissor()-functions. So, 'scissor' is Three.JS's terminology for cropping the viewport?

Comment: It is the termknology for masking part of the viewport. Note the canvas will remain the same size, and the scene will not "move left".

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to position a second canvas over your Three.js canvas, then re-draw the three.js scene onto your second canvas by blitting:

```
overlayCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(threeCanvas, 40, 40, 960, 960, 0, 0, 1200, 1200);
```

You can read more about the parameters to drawImage() in the [documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage), but what this does is crop a certain area of the three.js canvas and stretch it over a larger area of your second canvas. It should be much faster than rendering the scene a second time, and it will display at the size you want it (albeit with some stretching).

You can alleviate the stretching by drawing the original (three.js) scene at a larger size than it would normally be displayed such that the area you want to crop into view is the same size as your secondary canvas.